# How to include value from JSON data in BEM class modifier in Vue.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, bem

I would like to include the value of `title` in the class name on a tile to follow the BEM naming conventions I'm using. How can this be done?

Here's what I've tried:

```
<h2 :class="{
  'title': true,
  'title--${item.title}': true
}">{{ item.title }}</h2>
```

But it ends up looking like:

```
<h2 class="title title--${item.title}">Title</h2>
```

Comment: did you try `'title--'+item.title: true`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I did. I got the error "- invalid expression: Unexpected token + in"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Paul's answer pretty much covers your need. I just want to add that if you want to apply the class conditionally using Vue's class bindings then you can make use of [ES6's computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) ..

```
<h2 :class="{
  'title': true,
  [`title--${item.title}`]: true
}">{{ item.title }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to basically have nested strings and bind, or just use a variable in your component.

If you want to do the nested strings, you can do it like this:

```
<h2 v-bind:class="title + ' title--' + item.title">Title</h2>
```

Note you can also use the bind shorthand:

```
<h2 :class="title +' title--' + item.title">Title</h2>
```

If you want to calculate the whole shebang instead, you can just make it a function that you define later:

```
<h2 :class="getClass(title, item)">Title</h2>
```

Then later in your component definition:

```
methods: {
  getClass (title, item) {
    return `${title} title--${item.title}`
  }
}
```

Note upon rereading your question, I'm making an assumption.  I'm assuming that you have two props, `title` and `item`, and that `title` and `item.title` are different.  Feel free to adjust if I'm mistaken.